# In civivolunteer, is it possible to allow multiple users for 1 email?

Tags: civivolunteer, duplicate-contacts

Quick info:

- Wordpress: 4.7.1
- CiviCrm: 4.7.15
- CiviVolunteer 4.6-2.2.1

We are working with a group of often older volunteers that may only have one email address for two or more people.  Is there a way to allow them to register under this same address?  Currently, the system automatically replaces the name for anyone that has the same email address, making it difficult to sort the volunteers out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer: Yes, it's possible.

You're asking about the "Unsupervised Dedupe Rule" - that is, the test to determine whether a contact who fills out a public-facing form is a duplicate of someone already in the database.

Documentation can be found [here](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/4.6/common-workflows/deduping-and-merging/#dedupe-rules), and I definitely suggest reading it before making changes.  However, the general idea is to make up a different dedupe rule (e.g. "same email AND same first name" might be better in your case).  Then go to **Contacts menu » Find and Merge Duplicate Contacts**, create the new rule, and make it the new "Individual Unsupervised" dedupe rule.